# I got an error after trying to set a spawn location for a custom creature using Keira3

Tags: azerothcore

I assume that Kiera3 is part of AzerothCore, so I thought it would be ok to ask here.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XsKp.png) - the fields listed

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4vq2.png) - the error message received

(I am new to all of this, so I am not sure what exactly that means)

I attempted to look in the creature documentation that was linked at the top of the page... modelid did not exist. https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature

This error happens even when I fill out the other values.

I tried to change different values that would allow modelid to work. I changed modelid to the same modelid that is on the creature template, I tried to have it as 0, I tried to leave it blank.

I expected it to be able to execute the query, setting the spawn position etc. for the custom npc that I had created.

Answer (score 2):

Please check your core and Keira and update both to the latest version. They seem to mismatch.

Comment: I reinstalled the latest version of Kiera and pulled to update the core. Configured and generated, then compiled. Is it possible that it is a bug on Kiera's end?

Comment: I am not sure, which version of mysql are you using? the Keira version is 3.5.1? What about AzerothCore version?

Comment: MySQL - 8.0.32 (I believe is the latest version)
Kiera3 - 3.5.1 (I believe is the latest version)
AzerothCore - I don't exactly know how to check the version, but I had setup my server with all the latest versions when I made it the day I made the original post... I also have been pulling etc to update the core.